# sed - replace jira macro in confluence space

Tags: sed, confluence

Think i'm very close to my solution but i don't see what's wrong with this expression. I checked this expression within an editor, which works fine. But same should work with sed, so that i can run it with a shell script.

What i did.
I exported a Confluence Space and like to import to another Confluence. This confluence does not know the JIRA Server as an Application Link and it will not get.

So that's why i want to replace the macro with a link.

```
<ac:structured-macro ac:name="jira"><ac:parameter ac:name="columns">key,summary,type,created,updated,due,assignee,reporter,priority,status,resolution</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name="server">JIRA</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name="serverId">797a864e-7adf-3e88-ae1f-f35e5aade3f4</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name="key">IT-1234</ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro>
```

I tried the following to replace the macro. But didn't work yet. Can somebody help me with this expression, and explain what i'm doing wrong?

```
sed -i -E 's/<ac:structured-macro ac:name="jira">.*?((?:IT|BI)-[0-9]+).*?<\/ac:structured-macro>/http:\/\/www.myconfluence.com\/browse\/\1/gI' "confluence-space/entities.xml"
```

I get the result:
sed: -e expression #1, char 130: Invalid preceding regular expression.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show your `ac` namespace declaration?

Comment: There is no namespace url or declaration given within the entities.xml. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `(?:x)`(non-capturing groups) syntax with sed.

`(?` will search for zero or one occurrence of... nothing because `(` is not interpreted as a litteral character but as an opening capturing group.

Try this:

```
sed -i -E 's/<ac:structured-macro ac:name="jira">.*?((IT|BI)-[0-9]*).*<\/ac:structured-macro>/http:\/\/www.myconfluence.com\/browse\/\1/g' file
```